# meaning of つかなく and can word ending in ない be conjugated as i adjectives?

Tags: word-choice, words, conjugations, sentence

Hi i was trying to find the meaning of つかなく used in this sentence
this is from oregairu ep 11 of the 1st season they are talking about how the line towards the theatre is getting out of hand

あのままだと収拾つかなく なるんじゃねえのか

but since it has more than one meanings i can't seem to decide and also is it possible for verbs ending in ない be conjugated like an i adjective? because i parsed the word as つかない+く conjugation to make it an adverb =つかなく

Comment: Looking up the full expression might clear it up. https://jisho.org/search/%E5%8F%8E%E6%8B%BE%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

収拾 by itself means "settling" or "order", but you have to remember 収拾がつく as a set phrase meaning "to go under control". Verbs like つく, とる, かける each have dozens of meanings, and you have to learn their usages by examples.

[`ku-form + なる` is a common pattern](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B-naru-meaning/), but here it is used with ない, which conjugates like an i-adjective.

- 収拾がつく: to go under control
- 収拾がつかない: not to go under control
- 収拾がつかなくなる: to become not to go under control → to go out of control